# What were the major introductions made by the so called rashidi caliphs in terms of public administration?

Tags: history, khilafah, rashidi-caliphs, government

At the time of Muhammad () one could say that the Islamic government had his base in Medina or wherever he actually was. As far as I know there were no state officials nor a treasury etc. these kinds of things have come later due to the extension of the "Empire" and other facts.

To make this question reasonably focused: I'd like to have a list of the major introductions in terms of the public administration that have been created during the time of the four Rashidi caliphs () and the necessity leading to it!

Historical evidences are highly appreciated.

Comment: Who are the Rashidi caliphs you mean al khulafah ar rashideen i.e abu bakr umar رضي الله عنهم etc

Comment: @AbuhaneefMusa there are only four rashidi caliphs namely Abu Bakr, 'omar, 'Othman and 'Ali.

Comment: Sorry because i just want to understand your question fully before answering you said "so called rashidi caliphs" dont you view them to be rightly guided? And when you say innovations do you mean they done bidah?.

Comment: @AbuhaneefMusa by innovation I certainly don't mean bid'ah, but as mentioned necessary new improvements or tools to run and rule an expanding state. I've changed the term into introduction to make it less sound like bid'ah!

Comment: Ahsanu allahu ilayk forgive me i just had to ask before jumping to conclusions because I knew you wouldnt mean that. Ba ra kallah feek